# need to use pop function twice to remove last element from the array (perl)

Tags: perl

I've just started to learn Perl and joined Euler project to practice coding. This is the first exercise I did. The task was: "If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000." My solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers = (1..1000);
my $counter = 0;
my @all_array = ();
my $total = 0;

foreach $counter (@numbers) {
    if (($numbers[$counter] % 3 == 0) or ($numbers[$counter] % 5 == 0)) {
        push (@all_array, $numbers[$counter]);
    }
}

pop (@all_array);    #after that the last digit is still in place
pop (@all_array);    # only now the number 1000 is removed

my $tot = eval join '+', @all_array;      #returns correct value
print $tot;
```

The final element of the array is 1000. It seems as if it is followed by a space so to remove the number and get the correct result I have to use the pop function twice. The use of local $"='' changes nothing. Besides, I'm getting a message: Use of uninitialized value within @numbers in modulus (%) at C:\Users\Greg\Documents\perl\unt.pl line 10.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: To loop over the indicies of @number, `foreach $counter (0..$#number)`.  What you have is aliasing $counter to each element in @number in turn (which would work if you used just $counter instead of $numbers[$counter] everywhere in your loop body)

Comment: Thank you @Dillon. Using foreach `foreach $counter (0..$#numbers)` solved the problem.

Comment: You may have tagged the wrong person- I merely edited your post for formatting. I think you meant to tag @ysth

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through your code:

- `@numbers` is an array with the numbers from 1 to 1000

  - Why do you include 1000 in the list when the exercise says "less than N"?
- the for loop

  - assigns each of the numbers to `$counter`, i.e. 1, 2, ...
  - you use `$counter` as index into `@numbers`

    - why do you do that when `$counter` is already the number you are looking for?
    - Perl arrays start at index 0, so you have an off-by-one error
    - you never check `1` because your first number will be `$numbers[1] == 2` (OK, doesn't cause an incorrect result for the task at hand...)
    - you access one element *behind* the array, i.e. `$numbers[1000] == undef`
  - calculating with `undef` will cause a warning
  - `undef % 3 == 0` is true, hence...
- the first `pop()` will remove `undef` (from `$counter == 1000`)
- the second `pop()` will remove `1000` (from `$counter == 999`)
- then you use `eval` on a string `3 + 5 + 6 + ...` a very inefficient way to do a sum :-)

---

Wouldn't it be just a simpler approach to calculate the sum while running over the numbers from 1 to N-1? F.ex.:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
    my $sum = 0;

    foreach my $number (1..$arg - 1) {
        $sum += $number
            if ($number % 3 == 0) || ($number % 5 == 0);
    }

    print "${arg}: ${sum}\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl 10 100 1000 10000
10: 23
100: 2318
1000: 233168
10000: 23331668
```

Comment: or just `$sum = List::Util::sum grep $_ % 3 == 0 || $_ % 5 == 0, 1..999`

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. Much nicer solution than mine. And finally I understand why I had `undef` in the last element. Much appreciated!